# Icon of string.xml changed

Tags: android

My `string.xml` icons in android studio changed to bellow image, Why?

[image]

Comment: did project build successfully?

Comment: @ Redman.Yes, project build successfully

Answer (score 2):

I use from `mark as xml` and good work now.

[image]